# Generating client certificates for applications using Quickbooks Online Edition

Tags: quickbooks

I'm trying to get a certificate from the appreg.intuit.com area.  I have a webapp that was previously registered with mysubdomain.myhost.com as the host and myapp.myhost.com as the AppLogin.  Due to recent changes in some of our systems, we need to run the application that interfaces with QBOE from an IP address.  We have a certificate for the IP address that we created and is currently set up.

I created a new key in the java keystore with CN=123.456.78.9:myapp.myhost.com

Once I did this I generated a new cert request:

-----BEGIN NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----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-----END NEW CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----

When I try to paste this into the request area in the app registration, I get "ARSC262: common name not in hostname:applogin format.".  Which, it is in the right format as far as I know.  I also saw somewhere on the forums where you shouldn't add an email address or any optional fields.  I removed them with the same error message.  Is there something that I need to change so that my applogin matches the host or at least part of the host in some way?  Are they even related at all?  What other possibilites could the error message be pointing to besides just an incorrect format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Evidently, you can't use an IP address as the host name.  Here's the response I got from Intuit:

> The hostname has to be a DNS name and
>   cannot be an IP address.
>
> Regards,
>
> William Lorfing ᱖The hostname has to
>   be a DNS name and cannot be an IP
>   address.
>
> Regards,
>
> Intuit Developer Network